# Overwriting a parameter in config file during runtime

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm writing a node that reads a parameter from a config file (.yaml) to set the initial value of a variable (using ros::param::get). During runtime this variable is constantly updated. Before shutdown, I want to overwrite the parameter in the config file so that it takes the final value of my variable. Unfortunately ros::param:set doesn't work as it only updates the parameter in the server but not in the file (that will be read a the next launch).

Is there a simple way to overwrite a parameter in a config file  during runtime ? Or is dynamic_reconfigure the way to go ? It seems a bit overkill for the task I want to do ...

Thanks for your help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365202/overwriting-a-parameter-in-config-file-during-runtime/) by [Malkecero](https://answers.ros.org/users/61062/malkecero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may want to use [`yaml-cpp`](https://answers.ros.org/question/267467/yaml-dump-using-c/) to overwrite the yaml files.

Alternatively, you can use `rosparam dump` as shown in https://answers.ros.org/question/267467/yaml-dump-using-c/. (This may be overkill, as all parameters are recorded in this case. )

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Malkecero](https://answers.ros.org/users/61062/malkecero/) on 2020-11-22**:
yaml-cpp seems the right solution to my problem. Thanks !